# Pass complicated string to a variable OR pass variables into EOF

Tags: bash, variables, awk, while-loop, eof

UPDATED as requested

a few basic date variables that will be used in here.

```
month=$(date +%b)
day=$(date -d "today" '+%d')
```

Now...

I have a string that i need to assign to a variable it has got a lot of special characters as well as variables like `$month $day`

```
awk  '\$0 >= "$month$day 00:00:00" && \$0 <= "$month$day 23:30:00" && !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F "NameOfSoemthing " '{print \$2}'
```

the only way to assign it to a variable was to use EOF, this way...

```
read -r MyVariable << EOF
awk  '\$0 >= "$month$day 00:00:00" && \$0 <= "$month$day 23:30:00" && $line && !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F "NameOfSoemthing " '{print \$2}'
EOF
```

the output is as expected

`echo $MyVariable`

```
awk '$0 >= "Feb10 00:00:00" && $0 <= "Feb10 23:30:00" && && !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F "NameOfSoemthing " '{print $2}'
```

and everything is perfect.

but now I have a file `file.txt` which will be updated every time when i run the script, the file contains user names which will be used in `MyVariable`.
example of the `file.txt` ...

```
User1
User2
User3
```

now I create a while loop to read from the file and add `$line` to `MyVariable`

`example1`

```
while read line; do
read -r MyVariable << EOF
awk  '$line && \$0 >= "$month$day 00:00:00" && \$0 <= "$month$day 23:30:00" && !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F "NameOfSoemthing " '{print \$2}'
EOF
done < file.txt
```

for a whole picture `MyVariable` will be used in that while loop at the end after `EOF` and before `done < file.txt`, it will be encoded and used on a remote server, like this...

```
echo -n "$MyVariable" > ToBeEncoded.txt
EncodedCommand=$(base64 -w0 /home/max/ToBeEncoded.txt)
sshpass -p MyPass ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt root@192.168.1.100 "echo "$EncodedCommand" | base64 -d | sudo bash"
```

so the output of the while loop looks like this..

`echo $MyVariable`

```
 && $0 >= "Feb10 00:00:00" && $0 <= "Feb10 23:30:00" && !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F "NameOfSoemthing " '{print $2}'
```

But what I have noticed, it depends where you place the `$line` at
for example if I place `$line` after the date and time like this ....

`example2`

```
while read line; do
    read -r MyVariable << EOF
    awk  '\$0 >= "$month$day 00:00:00" && \$0 <= "$month$day 23:30:00" && $line && !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F "NameOfSoemthing " '{print \$2}'
    EOF
done < UserUsed.txt
```

the output I get, looks like this...

```
&& !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F "NameOfSoemthing " '{print $2}'
```

so basically missing entire section.

the output I would like to have, would look something like this

```
awk 'User1 && $0 >= "Feb10 00:00:00" && $0 <= "Feb10 23:30:00" && !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F "NameOfSoemthing " '{print $2}'
```

or like this if the `$line` is placed after the date and time just like in the second example

```
awk '$0 >= "Feb10 00:00:00" && $0 <= "Feb10 23:30:00" && User1 && !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F "NameOfSoemthing " '{print $2}'
```

Hope this makes it a bit more clear, plz let me know.

Thank you

Comment: using `'awk ..${varName}....'` , varName will not have a value. you need to use dbl-quotes, and then escape any of the dbl-quotes you need inside your awk script, i.e. `"awk '{....\"$month$day 23:30:00\"...}'"` . Plus you have the `<<EOS` stuff to consider. Plan to spend some time debugging this to get it right.  Wrapping your `while` loop in `set -x` and (closing with) `set +x` may help you see how it is working. Good luck.

Comment: I don't see the part where you use `$line`.

Comment: it is in the second section, in the while loop, right after the $month$day 23:30:00 &&

Comment: I see it. So what do you intend to do with the `MyVariable` variable?

Comment: so then i will encode (base64) it and run this command on a remote server, it has been tested and it works, but now I need to go through a few lines in that file ( so basically the file contains users, the file will be updated everytime when the scripts runs) so cant make it static :(

Comment: @Max You really need to give more thorough details instead of making us imagine what you might be possibly doing. I didn't get anything useful from what you said. You're asking how to do X but you want to do Y. Try giving some psuedocode maybe. We dont like guessing and repeatedly revising suggestions after every clarification.

Comment: @konsolebox, i am not really concerned about the encoding part, it works fine, the only part is how to pass the variable to EOF or making a variable out of that complex string

Comment: I added `printf 'MyVariable=%s\n' "$MyVariable"` at the end of the loop body and ran it.  It printed what I expected: the same basic string for each line of the file, with `$line` replaced with successive lines from the file.  Precisely what do you want, and how does it differ from what you are getting?  Concrete examples (I want string ... but I am getting string ...) would *really* help.

Comment: Another way to assign the complicated string to the variable is: `MyVariable="awk  '\$0 >= \"$month$day 00:00:00\" && \$0 <= \"$month$day 23:30:00\" && $line && !/something/ && /something2/ && !/something3/ && !/something4/' /var/log/messages | awk -F \"NameOfSoemthing \" '{print \$2}'"`.

Comment: You say `I am trying to assign a string with special characters to a variable` but I can't tell in your question what that string is. Is it the awk command in the here doc or is it the output of that awk command (not shown) or something else? Please [edit] your question to show an example of the string you want to store in the variable and what you want to do with it (i.e. provide sample input and expected output).

Comment: @EdMorton , noted and updated to make it more clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there was something wrong with the file that was used for line (have never seen this before)
after re-creating the file was able to get what I was after by using the `example1`

an update file not corrupt, it was different forwmat.
I did use `dos2unix` command to format it, all worked...